# Azure Internal Load Balancer Ignoring 2nd VM

Tags: load-balancing, virtual-machines, azure, port-forwarding

I've got **2 Ubuntu VMs on Azure (classic VMs on old management panel.)** I created both of the under the same Cloud Service. I also created a load balanced endpoint `80 (public)` to `80 (private)` with both machines having this endpoint, protocol `HTTP` and probe path `/probe`.

When I browse to the IP of the cloudservice with both of the VMs running I get the response I am expecting.

If I shut down VM 2 and keep VM 1 running it still works, but when I shut down VM 1 and leave VM 2 I get a connection failure in the browser.

I've played around and VM2 is never getting any traffic directed to it. I have an endpoint on my app `/probe` which returns a non-cacheable response of status 200 for the Load Balancer probes. I tried testing them on the VMs by calling

`wget localhost/probe`

I tried this on both machines and get the correct output only when VM1 is running. When VM 1 is off and I run this command on VM 2 it fails to connect to the address. I think this is where the issue lies but can't figure out how to fix it.

**Update:**

I added logging to the applications and it only ever seems to be probing the first virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a Load Balanced endpoint on both virtual machines in the Azure Management Panel. Very silly mistake .

Also each virtual machine needs to have a valid endpoint, for me it was `<address>/healthcheck`. All this endpoint needs to do is always return a `non-cache-able response with status 200`. Nothing else is needed, Azure Internal Load balancer handles the rest.